# Error using list comprehension - ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, list, numpy, opencv, list-comprehension

I have been searching on here similar questions but can't find a solution that works.

I have a list of contours, which has eg ten rows, each row has a value eg [[[241 478]]] and a size eg (11, 1, 2). From this list I find the area by generating a rectangle and multiplying the x by y.

I want to remove any contours which are too small or too large, however any approach (including list comprehensions) I take results in the  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

How can I get around this? If there is already a solution on here please point me in the direction.

Thank you

edited to add traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-73-e9296f497e02>", line 15, in <module>
    cnts_keep = [x for x in cnts_list if x not in cnts_area]

  File "<ipython-input-73-e9296f497e02>", line 15, in <listcomp>
    cnts_keep = [x for x in cnts_list if x not in cnts_area]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Below is the code as it currently stands, where I store in a new list contours I don't want to keep (' cnts_area '), then compare with the original list (' cnts_list ') to delete them. I've also tried using .remove() and .pop() but get the same error message.

```
            cnt_area = []
            cnts_area = []
            for c in cnts_list:
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                cnt_area = w * h
                if cnt_area == 0:
                    cnts_area.append(c)
                elif cnt_area < min_area or cv2.contourArea(c) > max_area:
                    cnts_area.append(c)
                else:
                    pass

            cnts_keep = []
            cnts_keep = [x for x in cnts_list if x not in cnts_area]
```

Comment: Could you add the entire traceback to the question?

Comment: ok, added it to the q!

Comment: The error you added uses different code than the one pasted below. At any rate your issue is comparing `cnts_area` to `True`. With an `if` you don't need to manually compare to `True` so the code you posted in your question at the bottom should work.

Comment: Ah apologies, I added the wrong code! Like I said I tried a few different things. Ive now edited to add the correct traceback

Comment: Is `cnts_list` a 2-dimensional list (or more generally, a nested list/array)?

Comment: I think it is a nested array, so each element/row has a value that look similar to eg [[[330 210]]], and a size that looks like eg (42, 1, 1). So if I were to print an element in the list, what would print would be a long list eg: [[[  0   0]]

 [[  0  46]]

 [[  1  47]]

 [[  4  47]]

 [[  5  48]]....... [[166   0]]]

Comment: So your problem is that you run into NumPy broadcasting (or similar), where each individual element of `x` is compared to each individual element in `cnts_area`. It doesn't compare per 3D array; for that to occur, each list item would have to be an object, but that may not be what you want (it makes things problematic elsewhere). For example, try `print(cnts_list[0] == cnts_area)` above the offending line, to see what happens (probably a lot of output, but to get an idea): it's not a simple True or False value, nor an error: NumPy has its own way of handling such comparisons.

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense. Is there a way then to remove the elements/rows with the area that is too small, using the original list or two lists, or is it impossible to do? I just now had an idea to turn it into a dataframe, with a boolean column with True if the area is too large/small, then somehow remove the rows with True, and then drop the boolean column and turn back into a list. But seems very clunky and not sure it would work!

Comment: In both cases, you are testing an array (or part of one) in an `if`.  `if` only works with scalar, single, True/False, values.  If `x` is an array, then `x==0` is also an arrray.

Comment: Is there no way to solve this then?